# What is the commented line Code Size 0 in ILDASM and when it will be generated?

Tags: .net, c#-4.0

Currently i am writing an application, in which i have added some class libraries(.dll). If i open the dll in the ILDASM editor and click any method, i am able to see code which is written in that method. Intention is not to show my code when opened using ILDASM. Since my method has some key which is very confidential

Can anyone let me know, how to achieve this so that when someone opened in the ILDASM editor, he/she should not see my code?

[image]

Comment: Title and body of the question appear unrelated. Also, you can obfuscate some details but a determined attacker will always be able to recover the keys. Don't put secrets on *machines you don't control*.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The code shown in ILDASM **is the IL**. Without the IL, you literally don't have a program to run. It isn't your source code - it is an intermediate form that the JIT uses to generate the CPU-targeted opcodes. You can *obfuscate* it, and there are tools to do this at various price points from "free" to "enterprise" with different feature sets, but ultimately: you **cannot** stop code from being reverse engineered if you hand it to people. You could also look into AOT compilation (removing the JIT step).

Think how much the games industry spends on this, and they're often using unmanaged code in the first place - but: still readily cracked, hacked, and reverse engineered.

The only reliable way to make this impossible is: don't hand them the code. For example, use a web-service or similar for the security critical aspects. And *even then*, you still have the problem of bad actors *inside* your company leaking the data, or bad practices or hacks allowing it to become stolen.